# Asp.net Server.GetLastError don't have line number

Tags: asp.net, .net

when i look in the stack trace of a try/catch, i have the row of my code that throw exception.
if i don't manage try/catch to redirect to a custom page and get my last exception with `Server.GetLastError` i have a different stack trace.
for example:
with try catch i have my line reference
[image]

without try catch, on my custom page nothing
[image]

i tried also

```
Dim ex As Exception = Server.GetLastError.GetBaseException
Dim trace As New Diagnostics.StackTrace(ex, True)
```

as suggested in an other post, but is not working. i wrong something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how i solved:

```
Dim ex As Exception = Server.GetLastError()
            Dim StackTraces As New Diagnostics.StackTrace(ex.InnerException, True)
            Dim StackFrame = Nothing

            For Each StackFrame In StackTraces.GetFrames()
                If (StackFrame.GetFileColumnNumber() > 0) Then
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
```